# Is there a way to make custom function to power button in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-line

Is there a way to make pressing power button opens a specific application or running command-line instead of (shutdown , standby , hibernate , nothing ) on windows-10 ?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: @DavidPostill Is it possible at least for power button on keyboard not PC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power button does not generate a key-code that can be intercepted.
It is still possible to detect and block, but requires a program that blocks
its action while running.

The steps to doing it are described here. Future changes in Windows might disable
this solution.

- Set the power button action to Sleep
- Use the API functions
  [SetThreadExecutionState](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate)
  to disable sleep mode and
  [RegisterPowerSettingNotification](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerpowersettingnotification)
  to listen for advanced power notifications.
- On receiving the message, execute the desired program or script.

More detailed instructions are found
[on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18458390/165358).